# How transpose of a matrix helps in making better sense of the data

Tags: matrices, transformation

The transpose of a matrix is obtained by flipping it about its diagonal. What is a practical scenario where we gain better insight into a set of data points by transposing it?

Comment: Well, one idea is, when you consider the matrix $\textbf A$ as column vectors in linear algebra, $\textbf{A}\cdot \textbf{A}^T$ squares each value, allowing the calculation of the vector norms.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I cannot think about anything else than avoiding the need to rotate the head by 90 degrees to get that "better insight" when considering the matrix as a "table of data".